# Lower security setting dialog after changing sandbox settings

Tags: xcode, macos, appstore-sandbox

I am developing an app which plays midi files in Mac.
When I activated sandboxing I couldn't hear any midi playback, after googling a bit I found out that I need to add some things in my entitlements.plist file,

So according to one forum which I saw, I added

```
com.apple.security.temporary-exception.audio-unit-host
```

I get a dialog box asking me to lower security settings every time I run the app on any mac. This is not desirable, how can i disable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you see is described in TN 2247 by Apple. It looks like you have at least one Audio Component that isn't suitable for sandbox. But probably not the one playing MIDI.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2247/_index.html

Comment: yes, i do have fmodex library in the program. 

Could that be an issue?

Comment: Yes it did,,
Check this [blog](http://explicitgfx.wordpress.com/2013/10/23/apple-sandboxing-friend-or-enemy/) its got all the instructions